# What’s growing on my tomato plant? This is crazy!

Tags: tomatoes, growth, leaf

I’ve never seen anything like this. Looks like a fungus or moss or something. Brown, fur like, skinny stems, 1/2 to 1 inch long. [image]Not normal fungal issues, this is new to me… zone 7b

Comment: emoji reactions to posts in stackexchange are sooo missing here.. 

Answer (score 6):

This is [chocolate tube slime mold](https://ourwildyard.com/chocolate-tube-slime-mold-stemonitis-splendens/). I have never seen it grow on anything other than dead trees before. Your best course of action is to treat with a chlorothalonil fungicide since a copper sulfate fungicide could damage tomatoes. Chlorothalonil can be purchased under brand names Bravo, Echo, and Daconil.

Comment: Chocolate tube slime mould on tomato leaves and planter here: https://www.thedailygarden.us/garden-word-of-the-day/chocolate-tube-slime "Slime molds have the bizarre ability to move across materials in their search for food. They do this so efficiently that city planners now use some slime molds to design roads and electrical grid systems." "Bizarre" just about sums it up. Also, "Since chocolate tube slime molds feed on decaying organic matter, they will not harm your tomatoes or other garden plants."